# I can't open multiple instances of .exe program with batch file [99% there]

Tags: windows, batch

I have this line of code:

```
@echo off

rem set the path to the Spek executable
set spek=C:\Program Files (x86)\Spek\spek.exe

rem set the path to the audio files
set audio_path=P:\Muzyka\complete\Album

rem loop through all audio files in the specified directory
for %%a in (%audio_path%\*.mp3) do (

  rem open the audio file in a new Spek window
  start "" %spek% "%%a"
)
```

And I want to open 2 songs in that folder, why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have delimited the `spek` variable's value with double quotes since the path has spaces in it:

```
 set spek="C:\Program Files (x86)\Spek\spek.exe"
```

I tested the .bat file after modification and it works!

Comment: oh shit you're right

Comment: @R2RVFX Please accept the answer if there is nothing else I can help.  Welcome to superuser.SE !

Comment: If there's space in folder name do I name it differently like with '_' instead of ' ' or do I keep it?
Edit: ok nvm it works

Comment: @R2RVFX If you're referring to the audio_path variable, I would also delimit the value with double quotes, just like the spek variable.  That way you don't have to worry about spaces.  But if you're referring to the MP3 file name, you already have double quotes between %%a so you should be okay (I tested it).